# Query conversion - Sql to Hql

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have this query and I need to convert it in hql but I am little confused, don't know how to write condition presented in 'where' clause in hql.

```
SELECT
    message 
FROM
    p_message 
WHERE
    message_id=(
        SELECT
            a.scene 
        FROM
            p_config a 
        INNER JOIN
            p_rec_type b 
                ON a.email_id=b.email_id 
                AND rec_type=2 
        WHERE
            a.email_type=1
    )
```

what is hql equivalent of this sql query?

Comment: you coould just use hibernates native query functionality

Comment: can u pls show me how, write code for this query?

Comment: You need to show the relevant entities and mapping information.  Remember that Hibernate HQL deals with your domain (Object) model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below the HQL query:
Assuming that p_message  & p_config  are domain object names & others are attributes mapping to column.

```
  String hqlQuery =" SELECT message  FROM     p_message  pm WHERE pm.message_id in (SELECT a.scene FROM p_config a INNER JOIN  p_rec_type b  ON a.email_id=b.email_id AND rec_type =:rectype          WHERE a.email_type=:emailTYpe)"; 
    query = session.createQuery(hqlQuery);
    query.setParameter("rectype", 2);
    query.setParameter("emailTYpe", 1);
```