# Convert SQL query to HQL or map result to hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have below SQL query

```
select column1 ,column2 ,column3 ,column4 ,column5 ,column6 from (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column2 ORDER BY null desc) rn,column1,  
column2 ,column3 ,column4 ,column5 ,column6
from TBLCUSTOMERSUBMODULERELATION where column1 = 'somevalue' AND column3 ='somevalue')
where rn=1;
```

i want to convert this query to HQL.
In my code `column1,column2,column3` is `EmbeddedId`
I have tried to convert or mapped directly this result in my class object using below code

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(qry);
sqlQuery.addEntity(CustomerSubModuleRelationBean.class);
```

but it gives error like `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name`

Is anyone have idea how to use convert this native SQL to HQL or map my result directly to entity class in Hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

You can try convert your sql query to hibernate query with adding some alias names to query statement

### Check here : [Query conversion - Sql to Hql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401003/query-conversion-sql-to-hql)

You are after a native SQL query.

If you are using JPA the syntax is:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select foo.* FROM Foo foo " +
                               "where f.x = max(f.x) over " +
                               "(partition by f.y)", Foo.class);
```

If you need to return multiple types, take a look at the [SQLResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html) annotation.

If you're using the the Hibernate API directly:

```
Query q = session.createSQLQuery("select {foo.*} from Foo foo " +
                                 "where f.x = max(f.x) over "+
                                 "(partition by f.y)");
q.addEntity("foo", Foo.class);
```

See [10.4.4. Queries in native SQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying-nativesql) in the Hibernate documentation for more details.

In both APIs you can pass in parameters as normal using `setParameter`.

---

Use this way to initialize your `sessionFactory` instead of `openSession` method.

```
SessionFactory factory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                             .configure()
                           //.addPackage("com.xyz") //add package if used.
                             .addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class)
                             .buildSessionFactory();
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I have tried this but my query contain SQL function which is not supported in hibernate. have you any idea about how to use `over partition by` function in hibernate?

Comment: have you try to run this query on database ? what's result ? are you sure this columns are defined in your hbm files correctly ?!

Comment: i am using Annotation based entity declaration. and query is SQL query not HQL and its run without error in database side.

Comment: Great!! you saved my time.